# What can schools see on your iPhone

Tags: iphone, monitoring

If you have connected your iPhone to the school's network by using your user name and password, can they see text messages you have sent while connected to their network? In addition, can they go back and access text messages you've sent while not on their network once you have reconnected?

Comment: What sort of text message? SMS? Or Whatsapp?

Comment: If the iPhone is your private one unrelated to the school then you should be safe because Apple only uses encrypted connections for their services (assuming you don't have installed and use other apps while on the schools network). And SMS don't go through a Wifi, they use the mobile network.